# Getting data from a string defined table name filtered on a string defined field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to return the contents of a Where filtered table of dynamic type based on a dynamic field name from an array of values.

Heres what I have so far:

```
public JsonResult GetRelationShips(string linkingTable, string idField, int[] ids)
    {
        var tableType = typeof(context).GetProperty(linkingTable);

        var entityTable = tableType.GetValue(db) as IQueryable;

        var method = typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains");

        var eParam = Expression.Parameter(tableType.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

        var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(ids.ToList()), method, Expression.Property(eParam, idField));

        var func = typeof(Func<,>);

        var genericFunc = func.MakeGenericType(tableType.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0], typeof(bool));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(genericFunc, call, eParam);


        var results = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Where").First().Invoke(db, new object[] { lambda });

        return Json(results);
    }
```

That last line is giving me an error:

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Honestly, I cobbled this together this afternoon from snippets from all over the internet. I have no idea what I'm doing here, this is new to me and I'm keen to learn. Just trying to avoid SQL injection, the rest of the project is entirely Linq so I'm soldiering on. I'm learning Generic types too, got my head around that, don't see how I can use them here though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There any many flaws in this single line of code:

```
var results = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Where").First().Invoke(db, new object[] { lambda });
```

- Trying to call `Enumerable.Where` instead of `Queryable.Where`. This would cause retrieving the whole table data and performing the filtering in memory instead of the database side.
- Trying to call potentially wrong method. `Where` has 2 overloads, and it's undefined which one will be returned as first by the reflection.
- Trying to invoke generic method definition, causing the exception you are getting. You have to first construct a generic method by using `MakeGenericMethod` and invoke that.
- Trying to invoke *static* generic extension method via reflection as if it is *instance* method. Instead, you should pass `null` as first argument to `Invoke` and pass `new object[] { entityTable, lambda }` as second argument.

You can avoid all these traps by simply using the C# dynamic method dispatch:

```
IQueryable results = Queryable.Where((dynamic)entityTable, (dynamic)lambda);
```

The whole code can be simplified by using the following [`Expression.Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Type_System_String_System_Type___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___) overload:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type, 
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments);
```

which is very useful for "calling" static generic extension methods:

```
var query = (IQueryable)db.GetType().GetProperty(linkingTable).GetValue(db);
// e =>
var entity = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "e");
// ids.Contains(e.idField)
// = Enumerable<int>.Contains(ids, e.idField)
var containsCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    nameof(Enumerable.Contains),
    new Type[] { typeof(int) },
    Expression.Constant(ids),
    Expression.Property(entity, idField)
);
// e => ids.Contains(e.idField)
var predicate = Expression.Lambda(containsCall, entity);
// query = query.Where(predicate);
query = Queryable.Where((dynamic)query, (dynamic)predicate);
```

You can also avoid the dynamic `Where` call and use similar `Expression.Call` based approach to "call" it, combined with `IQueryProvider.CreateQuery`:

```
// query.Where(predicate)
// = Queryable.Where<ElementType>(query, predicate)
var whereCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    nameof(Queryable.Where),
    new Type[] { query.ElementType },
    query.Expression,
    predicate
);
// query = query.Where(predicate)
query = query.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCall);
```

I've provided all that just because you said you are keen to learn. The simplest way of handling such tasks (and not reinvent the wheel) is to use some 3rd party package. For instance, with [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) package the whole code would be:

```
var query = ((IQueryable)db.GetType().GetProperty(linkingTable).GetValue(db))
    .Where($"@0.Contains({idField})", ids);
```

Comment: Thank you for all this, it looks good. I haven't had time to do anything today. One question; is that System.Linq.Dynamic option still SQL Injection proof?

Comment: It's basically string to LINQ `IQueryable` query translator, so no SQL or any type of executable code is involved at all.

Comment: Slight change to the dynamic linq: var query = ((IQueryable)db.GetType().GetProperty(linkingTable).GetValue(db)).Where($"@0.Contains(outerIt.{idField})", ids); http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html But thank you, this works. I've decided to go with the 3rd party suggestion, because it makes the project easier to debug for the rest of the team.